# How to interperet audio magnetotelluric results?

Tags: geophysics, geomagnetism, electromagnetism

I'm newbie in filed of Geophysics science. I will be grateful if you could help me to understand this chart [image: Text]

1. what does line 12 or Line 11 mean? what about line15-14?
2. How to identify the depths?
3. what does other numbers mean in the chart (such as 40 or 13 on the chart)
4. This diagram shows me the resistivity on the surface of earth of resistivity to depth of the earth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. These are acquisition lines id: each line provided a profile, the profiles are then joined to provide the current chart.
2. you cannot, they have already been filtered, the depth are defined.
3. 40 and 13 along the lines is the resistivity values along that isoline
4. It tells you the resistivity for the depth between 200 and 300 meters, as obtained via inversion of the collected measurments.

Comment: I really appreciate your answers. 1) Do these lines are the position of sensors? could you provide me more details? How these lines are obtain in these details? 2,3,4)Thank you,

Comment: Is there any good book about this subject?

Comment: Dear @JohnJin, reg. 1) each black point is a sensor, which records data for a long time (it can be days or weeks). After one line of data has been collected, the line of sensor is moved. Then the data are inverted to obtain the value of interest (usually each line individually, then merged statistically to form a 3d volume). "Inversion problem" is one of the main topic of geophysics. 
Infact, when you ask about a good book, you are asking about a good geophysics book. There are many, tailored to different knowledge levels. If you have no math and no geology background, I would suggest you:

Comment: https://www.geoexpro.com/articles/2018/04/an-introduction-to-exploration-geophysics-with-recent-advances

Comment: I am appreciative of your response.